# Flutter Check if wlan is active

Tags: flutter

How to check if Wlan is activated with flutter? 
I want to preload videos if the user doesn't use mobile data. 
So is there any way to determine if wlan is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [connectivity](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/connectivity/README.md) plugin that does that.
It can't tell you though whether the network allows to access the internet.

> This plugin allows Flutter apps to discover network connectivity and
>   configure themselves accordingly. It can distinguish between cellular
>   vs WiFi connection. This plugin works for iOS and Android.